# Unable to install Netbeans 6.9 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: netbeans

Unable to install netbeans 6.9.1 to ubuntu 12.04

```
root@cybage-virtual-machine:/home/rdas/Downloads# ./netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh Configuring the installer... Searching for JVM on the system... Extracting installation data...

Installer file /home/rdas/Downloads/netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh seems to be corrupted
```

Comment: 1) Try downloading it once again
2) Ubuntu is on a virtual machine?
3) I am sorry to say, but I am fed up with Netbeans. It hangs up most of the time, crashes and sometimes works very sluggish on bigger projects. I went back to cscope + vim and find it better

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-download the installer file.

Is there a reason for downloading an older version of NetBeans? The latest version in the 12.04 repository is 7.0.1 and the latest release version from [their website](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) is 7.2.1.

The 7.0.1 version can be installed either from the Synaptic Package Manager or from the Ubuntu Software Center.

From the command line, run the following:

`sudo apt-get install netbeans`

Comment: yes sudo apt-get install netbeans install the 7.0.1 version but I need specifically netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: I am not able to instaall 6.9 or older version in ubuntu 12.04 it sucks

Comment: OK. Fair enough. Did you re-download the installer or try to simplify your directory structure as suggested by Sumit?

Comment: had redownloaded and also try it same

Comment: My folder structure is simple /home/rdas/Downloads ...Even I tried /home/cybage/netbeans.sh but iiiiit was not worked

Answer (score 0):

Re-download and also compare the MD5 of your download and the one provided in the download section of your specific version. I'm also using 12.04 and installed NetBeans 6.9 (I usually wait some time to updated to a newer version because all that is new needs fixing so even if a newer version is available and I need to install it, I take an older one) less than a month ago. No problems installing it.